# Tilemill/mapbox comment box functionality

Tags: dictionary, comments, mapbox, tilemill

I'm trying to find a plugin on tilemill or mapbox enabling user comment functionality within a marker pop-up information box. Is this available?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that's built in. Are you trying to support comments on markers? If so, you would use [Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/) and something like [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) to handle comments and the [Leaflet bindPopup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) function to bind the popup.

If it's on something you're already designing in TileMill, you'd do the same thing, except with a `L.mapbox.gridControl` with the `sanitize: false` option.